# Installing NuGet packages on an offline PC is giving me an UntrustedRoot error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget

My work pc has no internet connection.

I copied the latest Entity Framework nuget package into c:\packages

I added it as a local nuget repo and unchecked the nuget.org one.

When I try to add the package to the project, I get the error:

> Package 'EntityFramework 6.4.4' from source 'C:\packages': The author primary signature found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

I guess my machine needs some kind of certificate adding, but I am not sure what certificate, or where.

Could anyone advise?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to run a Windows Update - and I guess that will require a (temporary) internet connection.

Comment: It looks like windows update runs regularly on this machine, I guess they have an update server within the VPN. But would be good to confirm, I just don't know what certificate I am looking for.

Comment: It seems it's a little hard to confirm the specific certificate. I'm not sure, but will `Run` > `certmgr.msc` list/locate the trusted/untrusted certificate?